# I'm trying to relearn GCC C or C++ compiling help please

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, 64-bit, x11

TWO QUESTIONS HERE:

according to this in another post elsewhere --
"had to compile a 32-bit application using GNU gcc on the 64-bit version of Linux.

Luckily, gcc man page directed me to the '-m32' and '-m64' options. These options generate code for 32-bit or 64-bit environments, respectively.

The 32-bit environment sets int, long and pointer to 32 bits and generates code that runs on any i386 system.

The 64-bit environment sets int to 32 bits and long and pointer to 64 bits and generates code for AMD's x86-64 architecture."

I have this C program I modified adding features to it that I wanted and needed -- now that I have moved from a 32 bit Linux to a 64 Bit linux this program no longer works with 64 bit Linux.

before I get to ahead of myself --

Question: do I now have to re-compile it as a 64 bit program using m64 to get it to work?

when I recompiling it with the -m32 I get an error as well.

using Xlib.h

```
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:38:23: fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
```

I have already googled into this error -- looking at several posts and made sure I have build-essential installed, and it is.

and xlib.h are installed too.

is this looking for "sys/types.h" referencing the X11 or somewhere else? 
I have no idea how to fix this problem either.

Comment: Show some source code, and most importantly the real command line. Use the `-H` option to `gcc` to understand where are include files searched

Answer (score 0):

> Question: do I now have to re-compile it as a 64 bit program using m64 to get it to work?

If you already have a 32-bit executable, you should be able to run it on a 64-bit Linux. Provided you have the required 32-bit system libraries installed.

> when I recompiling it with the -m32 I get an error as well.

That most likely means you do not have 32-bit development packages installed.

Comment: thanks - I figures it out - I had to delete the old 'o' file then I put in CFLAGS -m64 in my MAKE file just for good measure then ran make again and everything worked out fine -- sudo make install -- all finished -- thanks!